# League of Legends analyze mode

Tags: league-of-legends

If you look on YouTube at the League of Legends top 5 team plays videos, you will see an *Analyze mode* that the host uses to highlight a specific fight.

**Can it or is it possible to download that tool for the *Analyze mode* after a game is recorded?**

And if there is such a tool, should I use a specific recorder?

Comment: What top 5 team play videos do you mean? do you have a link and a time where you can see this mode?

Comment: I may be thinking of the wrong thing, but isn't this just a normal spectator mode overlay that allows painting? Perhaps provide a link to an example

Comment: You may be able to do it through lolreplay (link: http://www.leaguereplays.com/ ). Even if it's not within the downloaded program, you may be able to find a modded version or something. Don't take my word for any of that though, just throwing ideas out that someone else may be able to build on.

Answer (score 2):

If this is what you are referring to:

Skip to 2:33 to watch the analyze mode.

Top 5 plays by protatoemonster, they use LoL replay to record, then edit it afterwards using a 3rd party program.

They posted a behind the scenes video of how it was done, check it out here:

Might I remind you that it is a very long and tedious process, which takes a lot of skills as well.

Edit: if you are still interested, the program is called maya, its a very straight forward program, it simply takes lots of time and effort to mater.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to find it somewhere, but that specific tool is never officially released. It is used by Riot employees and I believe one of the pros once said they could request the same tools to analyze their own scrims. It is possible it was leaked somewhere but it is definitely not released nor is it supported by Riot.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the ESPN style replay/telestrator setup they've got in the analyst studio, I don't think that's publicly available. There is a new feature in the spectator client that gives you a "teamfight mode", allowing you to strip away most of the overlay in favor of some simple portraits and healthbars at the bottom of the screen. Might make it easier for you to draw over your own replays if that's what you're intending.